# How to check if input is an enumeration type

Tags: enumeration, ada

I am reading input from the keyboard. The input is supposed to match one of the elements defined in an enumeration type. Here is an example of the enum type:

```
type NameType is (Bob, Jamie, Steve);
```

If I receive an input that is not one of these 3, Ada raises an IO exception. How do I handle this to where I can simply display a "try again" message and not have the program stop?

Comment: See also [_Compare a string input to an Enumerated type_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29030762/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an instance of [`Enumeration_IO`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-10.html) for `Name_Type`, say `Name_IO`. In a [`loop`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5.html), enter a nested [block](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-6.html) to handle any `Data_Error` that arises. When `Name_IO.Get` succeeds, [`exit`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-7.html) the `loop`.

```
with Ada.IO_Exceptions;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Ask is

type Name_Type is (Bob, Jamie, Steve);
package Name_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO (Name_Type);

begin
   loop
      declare
         Name : Name_Type;
      begin
         Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter a name: ");
         Name_IO.Get(Name);
         exit;
      exception
         when Ada.IO_Exceptions.Data_Error =>
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Unrecognized name; try again.");
      end;
   end loop;
end Ask;
```

Alternative approaches include these:

- `Name_Type'Value`, defined [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5.html#p52) and illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046078/230513).
- `Enumeration_IO.Get`, defined [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-10.html#p12) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5Bada%5D%20Enumeration_IO%20Get).

Answer (score -2):

You might try an unchecked conversion to get the value into a variable of NameType then call 'valid on that variable.

Edit to include the example from [ADAIC](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/95style/html/sec_5/5-9-1.html)

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Test is

   type Color is (Red, Yellow, Blue);
   for Color'Size use Integer'Size;

   function Integer_To_Color is
      new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Source => Integer,
                                    Target => Color);

   Possible_Color : Color;
   Number         : Integer;

begin  -- Test

   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get (Number);
   Possible_Color := Integer_To_Color (Number);

   if Possible_Color'Valid then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Color'Image(Possible_Color));
   else
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Number does not correspond to a color.");
   end if;

end Test;
```

Comment: You would be seriously mistaken to try this. In any case, what would the "value" be in the first place? an integer; a string? I suggest you try this yourself!

Comment: This is usually how I read in arbitrary data from a serial card. Then unchecked conversion it from the buffer to a typed structure. Then check each element in the structure with 'valid. If there is a better way could you enlighten us? I see the answer above that relies on exceptions as a normal act of program input. Seems unwise.

Comment: Both of the given solution have flaws. If a number is tried with the first example the program will continue to output the text of the exception, forever. The example that I give will throw an exception if non numerical input is presented.

Comment: To me, the question _requires_ that the user enter `bob` or `jamie` or `steve`, not `0`, `1`, or `2` respectively. I agree with your technique for reading arbitrary data (how else to do it?!). And I also agree with your criticism of @trashgod’s answer; the normal technique would be to read a complete line into a string and process that (using `Name_Type’Value` or [enumeration IO from a string](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-10.html#p12)). Both of these rely on exceptions for correct processing, I’m afraid.